# Need correction for solving logarithm inequality of $ \log_{x}{(x+3)} > \log_{x}{(2x)} $

Tags: inequality, logarithms

$$ \log_{x}{(x+3)} > \log_{x}{(2x)} $$
My work so far is

Step 1 : Finding the definition term for base of logarithm
$$ x > 0 \lor x \neq 1,x \in Real $$
Step 2 : Finding the definition term for  $\log_{x}{(x+3)}$
$$ x+3>0 $$
$$x>-3  $$
Step 3 : Finding the definition term for  $\log_{x}{(2x)}$
$$  2x>0$$
$$ x>0 $$
Step 4 : Unify the definition term from step 1 to step 3
$$ x > -3 \lor x >0 \lor x\neq 1 $$ 
$$\implies x>0 \lor x\neq 1 $$
Step 5 : Finding the inequality term 
I change the base of logarithm, for apllying the cancelation of "logarithm with x as its base"
$$ \frac{\log_{10}{(x+3)}}{\log_{10}{(x)}} > \frac{\log_{10}{(2x)}}{\log_{10}{(x)}}$$
I try multiply both side with $\log_{10}{(x)}$
$$ \log_{10}{(x+3)} > \log_{10}{(2x)} $$
$$ \iff x+3 > 2x$$
$$x-2x>-3$$
$$-x>-3$$
Multiply with –1
$$x<3$$
Step 6 : Finding the solution set
$$ = \{ x | 0<x<3, x \neq 1, x \in Real \}$$

I just finish it or i missed something to solve this inequality ?
Please, give your suggestion and help to explain. Thank you so much.

Comment: $\log_{10}{(x)}$ may be negative. You can't multiply both sides by a negative number and have the inequality  remain unchanged.

Comment: Why'd you change the base to $10$? Why not $e$ or $2$ or $\sqrt[27]{\pi}$.... or then simplest yet $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to proceed as follows.

Let $a= \log_{x}{(x+3)}$ and $b=\log_{x}{(2x)}$. Then,

$$a>b,\>\>\>\>\> x^a=x+3,\>\>\>\>\>x^b = 2x$$

Two cases:

1) $x>1 \implies x^a>x^b \implies x+3>2x$, which leads to  the solution $1<x<3$.

2) $0<x<1 \implies x^a<x^b \implies x+3<2x$, which has no solution.

Thus, $1<x<3$.

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestion. I can get some more knowledge.